# Usb ports not recognized ubuntu 22.04

Tags: usb, battery

I have installed ubuntu 22.04 for a near time and it was working well but suddenly I face this problem my USB ports work when my device is charging perfectly but when I unplugged the charger the USB ports don't recognize any of my devices and to be more specific the USB ports, in this case, work as long as I am in lock screen but after I enter my password and the desktop appear the USB ports are not working again I have tried many solutions most of them evolve editing  `/etc/default/grub` but it's not working for me I have also try to bind and unbind my drivers based on this article https://www.tech.trulyglobal.ca/2021/01/fixing-motherboard-audiousb-problems.html it works only when the laptop is unplugged then I plugged it so all it's do is save me from restarting my PC to make the ports work again does this problem consider a bug caused by the latest update because I think after the last update this thing has happened does anyone have a solution I have also notice that even the camera of my laptop aren't recognized except my laptop is plugged also thank you in advance